# trying to make a select option appear after choosing an option on the first select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select tag for category and I would like the second select option for subcategories to display after you select the category. also when I try to change the style of an element it keeps returning null
I think the JS is being applied before the element loads but I'm not sur how to fix it, any help would be appreciated thank you

```
<select onchange="displaySubCategory()" onchange="ChangeSubCategory()" id="item-category" required>
          <option class="blank-condition-value" value="">Select</option>
          <option value="Antiques">Antiques</option>
          <option value="Arts & Crafts">Arts & Crafts</option>
          <option value="Baby">Baby & Nursery</option>
          <option value="Books">Books, comics, magazines & Manga</option>
          <option value="Fashion">Fashion</option>
          <option value="Collectables">Collectables</option>
          <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
          <option value="Garden & Outdoor">Garden & Outdoor</option>
          <option value="Health & Beauty">Health & Beauty</option>
          <option value="Home & Furniture">Home & Furniture</option>
          <option value="Jewellery">Jewellery & Watches</option>
          <option value="Motor Vehicles">Motor Vehicles</option>
          <option value="Music">Music & Audio</option>
          <option value="Sports & Leisure">Sports, Fitness & Leisure</option>
          <option value="Toys & Games">Toys & Games</option>
          <option value="Tools & DIY">Tools & DIY</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="subcategory-box"> 
        <label id="subcategory-label" for="subcategories">Item Subcategory:</label>
        <select id="subcategories"></select>

.subcategory-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 35px; 
  display: none;
}
function displaySubCategory() { 
  const category = document.getElementById('item-category');
  const subcat = document.getElementById('subcategory-box');
  window.addEventListener('change', (onDOMContentLoaded) => {
  subcat.value.style.display ='inline-block'; 
  }) ;
};
```

Comment: A quick remark.. Typically, you don't want to set the value of the option to be the same as the label. I'd 're-value' yours to be from 0 to 16. The label is for people, the value is for computers. In my case, I'd make the value its index in some array. Later, you can use the value extracted from the control to index the original array if needed, or some other data.

Comment: @enhzflep That's not true at all. In fact, if you don't explicitly specify a `value` attribute for an `option`, then that `option`s `value` becomes its text (so the text and the value are the same). This is quite common and there's nothing wrong or out of the ordinary about doing that. Giving an index number as the `value` is not a good idea because 1) Now you've got an ordered set of numbers you need to maintain if options are added or removed and 2) the `option` elements form an array in the DOM, which will automatically have indexes anyway.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - Thanks for your thoughts Scott. It's always helpful to hear and consider alternate views. I come at this stuff as an old lover of assembly language. Though the part of me forced to endure DBs also prefers ints to strings. Your comment about added or removed options is worth its weight in Palladium, (many) thanks.

Comment: @enhzflep Remember though, that even if you did set the values as you suggest, they still wouldn't be ints because there is only one data type in HTML... string and all numbers in JavaScript are floats. You'd have to convert those strings to numbers in JavaScript to work with them as such. Also, the biggest thing to remember about form field values is that they are what gets submitted when a `form` is submitted, so receiving a name/value pair of: `item-category=1` would then require you to keep an indexed list of the actual category names on the server-side (yet more maintenance), when you ...

Comment: @enhzflep ... could instead just pass `item-category:Furniture`, which is much more succinct, and doesn't require nearly as much work to maintain.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus for another gem of wisdom. You've provided a couple of really good examples.

Answer (score 1):

You had "**subcategory-box**" as a class on the div element but in js, you were accessing it with **document.getElementById**. You can use document.getElementsByClassName('.subcategory-box')[0] or document.querySelector('.subcategory-box'').

Another option is to change the class to ID on the DIV element and change the subsequent CSS as well.

Here is the jsfiddle in which I have implemented all the approaches mentioned in the answer.

https://jsfiddle.net/8kagxhtz/

```
function displaySubCategory() { 
  const category = document.getElementById('item-category');
  
  // Use if you need to check if with id
  //const subcat = document.getElementById('subcategory-box');
  
  // If you need to use class on the element 
  //const subcat = document.getElementsByClassName('subcategory-box')[0];
  
  // Or use this for class
  const subcat = document.querySelector('.subcategory-box');

  subcat.style.display ='inline-block'; 

};
```

Comment: *You can use document.getElementsByClassName('.subcategory-box')[0]* **<-- [No, no, no, no, no!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)**

Comment: I have mentioned all possible options for this, preferably document.querySelector('.subcategory-box'). The document.getElementsByClassName('subcategory-box') is an option obviously not a preferred one.

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to get your code up to modern standards, [don't use inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) like `onchange`. Separate your JavaScript from your HTML.

Now, the error you mention is happening because your code is this:

```
const subcat = document.getElementById('subcategory-box');
```

But you don't have any element with that `id`. Instead, you have this:

```
<div class="subcategory-box">
```

But this has a `class`, not an `id`. So you need a line like this:

```
const subcat = document.querySelector('.subcategory-box');
```

And, then you'll still have an error because you then do this:

```
subcat.value.style.display ='inline-block';
```

you get the error because a `div` doesn't have a `value` property and even if it did, the `style` is a property of the element, not its `value`.

Next, this:

```
window.addEventListener('change', (onDOMContentLoaded) => {
  subcat.value.style.display ='inline-block'; 
}) ;
```

Doesn't really make sense for you to be passing an `onDOMContentLoaded` argument to a `change` event handler.

So here's what I think you are looking for:

```js
// Get references to the DOM elements you'll work with just once
const category = document.getElementById('item-category');
const subcat = document.querySelector('.subcategory-box');

// Set up your events in JavaScript, not in HTML
category.addEventListener("change", displaySubCategory);
category.addEventListener("change", changeSubCategory);

function displaySubCategory() { 
  subcat.classList.remove("hidden"); // Remove the CSS that is hiding the element
}

function changeSubCategory() { 

}
```

```css
/* Separate this into its own class
   so you can add/remove it separately
   from other styling. */
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="item-category" required>
     <!-- If you don't supply a value, then the value becomes the option's text -->
     <option class="blank-condition-value" value="">Select</option>
     <option>Antiques</option>
     <option>Arts & Crafts</option>
     <option value="Baby">Baby & Nursery</option>
     <option value="Books">Books, comics, magazines & Manga</option>
     <option>Fashion</option>
     <option>Collectables</option>
     <option>Electronics</option>
     <option>Garden & Outdoor</option>
     <option>Health & Beauty</option>
     <optio>Home & Furniture</option>
     <option value="Jewellery">Jewellery & Watches</option>
     <option>Motor Vehicles</option>
     <option value="Music">Music & Audio</option>
     <option value="Sports & Leisure">Sports, Fitness & Leisure</option>
     <option>Toys & Games</option>
     <optio>Tools & DIY</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="subcategory-box hidden"> 
   <label id="subcategory-label" for="subcategories">Item Subcategory:</label>
   <select id="subcategories"></select>
</div>
```